# Child Form is hidden behind MDI Parent Container

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, mdi

When a child form is opened it is hidden behind the title bar of MDI Parent Container.

[image]

The Child form's `WindowState` is set to `Maximized`. `FormBorderStyle` is set to `None`.

If I minimize the MDI parent and maximize it, then the child form comes in to front.

How to overcome this situation?

**Edit:**

I use the following code to open a child form.

```
    this.childForm= new ChildForm();
    this.childForm.MdiParent = this;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    this.childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.childForm.Show();
    this.childForm.BringToFront();
    this.childForm.Focus();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native Windows MDI implementation cannot deal with borderless MDI child windows.  Unfortunately, Winforms forgets to enforce that restriction.  You can move the WindowState assignment after the Show() call but that causes another problem.

Just don't make it borderless, the border isn't visible anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code.

```
    Form1 newMDIChild = new Form1();
    newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
    newMDIChild.Show();
    this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
    newMDIChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: @Marshal From Nazima's code, try adding that DockStyle.Fill property to your child forms.  Because of the borderless childform, the DockStyle will "realign" your child form properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
AboutBox1 ab = new AboutBox1();
ab.MdiParent = MDIForm.ActiveForm;
ab.TopMost = true;
ab.Show();
```

Comment: Please don't use a signature in your questions or answers. We already know you wrote it.